# how to check whether a user is a member of distribution list/security group in AD C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group

I am using below piece of code to check the whether a given user is part of distribution group in AD.

```
static bool IsUserMemberOf(string userName, string groupName)
{
  using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
  using (var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, groupName))
  using (var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName))
  {
    return userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(groupPrincipal);
  }
}
```

i am calling above method with values as `IsUserMemberOf("domain\\username","domain\\groupname")` 
But i see a null pointer exception because `groupPrincipal` is having null value.

Any help in this regard?

Comment: Your code works on my system.  Are you sure domain\\groupname is a valid group in the context you are using?  It might be worth examining `ctx.ConnectedServer` to make sure you are connected to the domain you expect to be connected to.  You could also try using a different group name just to check if your code fails with that.  The `userPrincipal.GetGroups()` function would give you a list of names you could use.

Comment: I also tried your code and it works for me as well. I omitted the domain\\ part from the user name and group name.

Comment: Also, is there a chance that your user is not in the same domain as the group being queried?  Your method will not work if that is the case.  Unfortunately, I don't have a solution to this problem.  I've had a similar problem and never could find a sufficient answer.

Comment: actually above code is working if both user and group name are in same domain. If i specify a group from different domain, i am seeing above behavoir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my Group is in different domain than the User which I am querying for:
I made below change to my program and working now.

and i am calling like this:

```
IsUserMemberOf("domain1\\username","domain2\\groupname")


static bool IsUserMemberOf(string userName, string groupName)
{
 using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"domain1"))
 using (var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"domain2"), groupName))
 using (var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName))
 {
    return userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(groupPrincipal);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It's just means that :

```
groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, groupName))
```

Returns a null pointer because your group is not in present in your domain. You just have to test your var `ctx`, `userPrincipal` and `groupPrincipal`.